# How open is Android for developers?

Tags: android

Long story short: How open is Android OS for developers?

A little in depth:
For instance, if I'm willing to write my own text-input interface, would it be possible (like, totally overwrite the built-in-phone one)? Or that's something like core feature and cannot be changed?

And, is there a difference for developers, whether I buy a Google phone, HTC or Samsung etc.?

P.S. If that's all possible, no warranty voids for such changes?

Hope I've made myself clear and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create [custom input method](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/creating-input-method.html). For development the best is Google phone, but in order to work on all hardware, especially a keyboard, you need to test on all the devices you want to be supported (try to borrow them instead of buying all of them :P)

Comment: I'm not interested in building an 3rd party application or such (for now..), so no worries on multiple devices. More like a custom "mod" for my own usage (and, the question about multiple devices was to see whether they deny access to more low-level features or not). And I am looking to override the "global" text-input, so it affects every input field.

Comment: You have the link where to start, to build the input.

Answer (score 1):

For android you can always do that..you need to download the source code from google repository. make the changes according to your wish for the global component, build the code and flash that to different device.

so you can always add your customized component to open source Android